# SML adding two pairs of numbers in a list

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm trying to take a list, for example [1,2,3,4], and add each pair of in the list to get a new list [3,7]. I keep getting an error and I don't know what it means. Any help would be appreciated.

```
fun listsum x =
if null x then 0
else hd x + hd(tl x) :: listsum(tl x) + listsum(tl(tl x));
```

stdIn:3.6-3.58 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload]

```
 operator domain: 'Z * 'Z list
  operand:         'Z * 'Y
  in expression:
    hd x + hd (tl x) :: listsum (tl x) + listsum (tl (tl <exp>))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here: the first is that in the last line, you are asking for the sum of two lists with `+`; the second is that you are returning an `int` in one branch of the `if`, and a `list` in the other.

The first problem just looks like a thinko: you've done all the addition you need in the left hand side of the `::`, all that remains is to recurse over the rest of the list.

Fixing both,

```
fun listsum x =
    if null x then []
    else hd x + hd (tl x) :: listsum (tl (tl x));
```

Comment: That makes sense, I see that I was trying to add two recursive statements when I had the math already finished and just needed one recursive statement. Hence the overload error. Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive function that pattern matches on the list. `listsum` throws an exception on an odd length list where as this one will ignore the last odd value.

```
fun sumTwo(xs: (int) list) =
 case xs of
   h :: ht :: t  => h + ht :: sumTwo(t)
   | h :: []  => []
   | [] =>  []
```

Tests:

```
- sumTwo [1,2,3];
val it = [3] : int list
- sumTwo [1,2,3,4];
val it = [3,7] : int list
```